# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to int

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error on the line where it says `ht.keySet()`:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to int

`ht` is a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

```
for (int key : ht.keySet())
{
    if(ht.get(key).size() == 0)
    {
         System.out.println("There is no errors in " + key) ;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: there are unexpected errors in " + key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a valid _for_ statement in Java. [Java "for" loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: @m0ski0: never heard of the `for-each`? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Java generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Declare `ht` as a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Foo>` where `Foo` is whatever data type you expect to be returned by `ht.get()`. Using the `Map` interface would be even better:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, Foo> ht = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Foo>();
// or preferably
Map<Integer, Foo> ht = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Foo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

ht is a `LinkedHashMap`, if it contains only `Integer`s, you should declare it as `LinkedHashMap<Integer,Object>`.

If it will be declared as `LinkedHashMap<Integer,Object>`, the unboxing to an `int` will be done automatically.

(*) even better if you declare it as `LinkedHashMap<Integer,[actual-object-type]>`

Answer (score 0):

It must be: `for (Integer key : ht.keySet())...`

`LinkedHashMap<K, V>` where K and V are Objects, not primitiv (int, short ...)

Comment: In Java 1.5+, autoboxing would take care of this. The real problem is in lack of generics.

Answer (score -1):

Use Integer instead of int and it will probably work.
The keys in the LinkedHashMap must be objects, not primitive types.

Comment: Should be taken care of by autoboxing I suspect.